# Re-entry attack using the transfer function

Tags: solidity

Is it possible to re-attack if you use the sending of ethers via the transfer function? Do I need to add some defensive logic to my contract in this case?

Comment: Re-attack ? What kind of attack ? Please provide more information.

Comment: Transfer and send are restricted to 2300 gas stipend, so there's not much room for an attack.